# OpenGL Fragment Shader VS DirectX Fragment Shader

Tags: opengl, directx, shader

In DirectX I know that I can do something like this.

```
struct GBufferVertexOut
{
    float4 position     : POSITION0;
    float4 normal       : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 texCoord     : TEXCOORD1;
};

GBufferFragOut GBuffersFS(GBufferVertexOut inVert)
{
    GBufferFragOut buffOut;
    buffOut.normal = normalize(inVert.normal);
    buffOut.normal = ( buffOut.normal + 1 ) * .5;
    buffOut.diffuse = tex2D( diffuseSampler, inVert.texCoord );
    buffOut.diffuse.a = tex2D( ambientSampler, inVert.texCoord ).r;
    buffOut.specular = float4( 1, 1, 1, 1 );

    return buffOut;
}
```

so my fragment result is a collection of information
I'm trying to convert an openGL shader to do something similar

but can you even do that?. I've never returned anything else before though an openGL fragment shader besides a vec4 for "Fragment Color" and i can't seem to find any information that does tell me i can return more.

Answer (score 2):

In opengl you define your output variables outside of the main function, and then set their values within that function. So the equivalent of the hlsl code you have there would be something like this (fragment shader)

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 diffuse;     //these are the outputs
layout (location = 1) out vec4 normal;
layout (location = 2) out vec4 specular;

in vec4 in_position;    //these are the inputs from the vertex shader
in vec4 in_normal;
in vec2 in_tex_coord;

void main()
{
    normal = normalize(in_normal);
    normal = (normal + vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)) * 0.5; 
    diffuse = texture(diffuseSampler, in_tex_coord);
    ambient = texture(ambientSampler, in_tex_coord);
    specular = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Then in your application you need to make sure that you have bound a framebufferobject which has the correct number and type of attachments to write to.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yeah i do have those variables in my vertex shader. are you saying I should manipulate the information there? because I was trying to get like "normal" data per pixel or keep track of the pixel position.

Comment: because I am keeping track of the image. I do bind my frame buffer. and I write to it. But in directX your fragment shader outputs all the info you tell it to throw out.

Comment: you mean when I'm using glFramebufferTexture2D? 
void glFramebufferTexture2D(GLenum  target,  GLenum  attachment,  GLenum  textarget,  GLuint  texture,  GLint  level);
I should be manipulating the attachment location? i been just using GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0

Comment: yeah you need to have a separate texture for each output. so you'll need a texture attached to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 and GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2. The attachment numbers correspond to the layout numbers in the shader

Comment: ok so basically i'll just be using multiple render targets? and i'll be needing like ( normalRenderTarget, colorRenderTarget ) ext.. attach them all ATTACHMENT[x], and just do my normal render process with the fragment shader having just "example" 3 "out vec4" variables if im doing 3 data collections?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to use [glDrawBuffers](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawBuffer.xml) so that you can render to multiple targets.

Comment: you saying i cant use glDrawElementsBaseVertex? never mind i understand now

Comment: thank you I'll try this and if it works I'll definitely be giving ya points =]. If not I guess i'll find a way to ask you a question :D

Comment: I'm going glDrawBuffers( 4, uiBuffersToDraw ); uiBuffersToDraw hold my 4 enums. then i do my binding. I get the glError GL_INVALID_OPERATION: is generated if any of the entries in bufs (other than GL_NONE ) indicates a color buffer that does not exist in the current GL context.

should i be doing my frame buffer binding before i call glDrawBuffers?

Comment: The active drawbuffers are part of the fbo state, so you must bind the fbo first.